Chrome Extension Manifest v3 - Copy to Clipboard
with manifest v2 i had this working nicely.. essentially i have a right click menu with choices that when I pick one, it copied to to the clipboard and then pasted it to the active text field the cursor was on..
now with manifest v3.. its broken lol.
any help would be greatly appreciated!!
***NOTE: the point of the ext is to set the focused text area text... it worked with v2 by setting the clipboard text then pasting.. but if there is a way to just set the text field value to the text i want (like a password autofill) that would be great too!
here is part of the onClick...

function onClickHandler(info, tab) {

    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        });
        
    if (info.menuItemId == 'test') { 
        SendText('1234');
    }
};

I think i have the manifest right, its just this code that doesnt work:
function SendText(strText){
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            code: "navigator.clipboard.writeText('" + strText + "').then(function(text) { document.execCommand('paste'); });"
          });
}

it throws this error:
Error in event handler: TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'injection': Unexpected property: 'code'. at SendText
***EDITED 5/13
